# Is there a reason for Symfony default structure to not decouple bundles?

Tags: symfony, directory, bundle

I read [this](http://blog.danielribeiro.org/yes-you-can-have-low-coupling-in-a-symfony-standard-edition-application/) article by a fellow stackoverflow member Daniel (hello if you're reading this!) on decoupling Symfony bundles which I found really interesting. I'm now in a position where I am about to start a new project from scratch and have been planning on following Daniel's guidance. However, it was written 2.5 years ago, and Symfony's latest releases haven't adopted the structure and neither is there any mention if it under Symfony's [Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html) article. Therefore, I'm wondering if there's a good reason Symfony themselves have not adopted the structure?

Without reiterating Daniel's whole article here, the directory structure he proposes is as follows (along with not using annotations for entities):

```
src/
└── Vendor/
    └── Product/
        └── Bundle
            └── BlogBundle/
            └── ForumBundle/
            └── SiteBundle/
                └── Controller/
                    └── IndexController.php
                └── Resources/
                    └── views/
                        └── index.html.twig
                └── ProductSiteBundle.php
        └── Entity
            └── User.php
        └── Repository
            └── UserRepository.php
        └── Service
            └── UserPasswordRetrievalService.php
```

Comment: If you are not going to use those bundles in other projects, its better to use ser/AppBundle and put your views in app/Resources so you have all of them in one place(much easier if you have a frontend person also working on the project) making several bundles just for the project might only be excused if for example there are several people working on separate parts of the project, otherwise, you're just multiplying unnecessary code(bundle files etc)

Comment: This looks great! To your question: It's very difficult to change a standard, event if it's incorrect, bad practice and teaches bad habits to new programmers event if it would not have to. Changing something like this sometimes create huge confusion and miss-use. This actually allows to use this package by various framework. I use this structure without knowing the article myself. Just Bundle directory is named Adapter, with Adapter\Symfony, Adapter\Nette inside.